# usin Simple.OData.Client at ||Xamarin app that targets .Net standard

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, odata

Hello I have started building a Xamarin forms app that will consume OData service. In most examples suggest to use Simple.OData.Client but when I add the nugget package I get the following Warrning.

Package 'Simple.OData.Client 4.29.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

PS : I have been away from .net since 3.5 so if someone shed some light about Core .Standard and the basic framework it will be great. Since I read a lot but I am not 100% sure I get the full concept

Answer (score 1):

Essentially the NuGet you are trying to consume is not compatible with .net standard 2.0 yet.

One small annoyance of the move to .netstandard is that any NuGet packages that wish to be consumed by .netstandard projects must be updated.

A short-term solution would be to use a more up to date client for OData like the following:

[OData Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OData.Client/)

UPDATE:

The package you are trying to consume has been updated to support .netStandard 2.0.

You just need to consume the pre-release version:

[beta version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Simple.OData.Client/5.0.0-beta2)

here is a link to the project owner discussing the changes

[Github Issue](https://github.com/object/Simple.OData.Client/issues/425)

Comment: Do you know of a package that support OData V3 as well

Comment: @HristoAlexsiev maybe this one:https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.OData/